# Excel Online OfficeJs diagnostics version incorrect

Tags: office365, office-js, excel-online

Why does OfficeJs show a different version number then the Info Screen? This also happens in PowerPoint Online but Word Online seems to be correct.

[image]

Comment: Are you on the Office "Click-to-Run" or Office MSI? Also, the UI of my "Info" page doesn't match yours. What are the steps you use to open it?

Comment: Ricky, I think this is Office Online, not Desktop (which I think is what your question is referring to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

Please track here for update: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/39

---

**UPDATE**:

Sorry for inconvenience. The reason is because different modules have slightly different version numbers and the API reports the version that matter most.

But if someone need do something based on this API version, please report back to us at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/39

*Disclosure: I am working for Microsoft.*